# How do I fix 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll?

Tags: c#

Every time I run my WinForms app, this exception shows up in Visual Studio. The app works completely as it should, the code has no errors.

This is the only part of the code that has something to do with file directories:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calcerPasswordCorrect cpc = new calcerPasswordCorrect();
            cpc.ShowDialog();

            string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
            filepath = filepath + @"\test.txt";
            TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath);
            sw.Write("Input: " + textBox4.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

The file that is supposed to generate, generates with the content.

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the issue? Have you looked at what `filepath` actually is by the time you try to write to it? (I'd also recommend using `File.WriteAllText` instead of manually opening the file then closing it - and if you *do* need to do that, use a `using` statement so that the writer is closed even if an exception is thrown while writing.)